# Convert directories with java files to java modules in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently switched to using IntelliJ. I manually imported some projects and I guess I didn't do it correctly. They are all supposed to be java modules but they are just regular directory folders. Is there a way to convert them to java modules so I can run the programs or will I have to manually recreate new modules?

[image]

Comment: Is your project gradle or maven based?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this. If your project has an existing build framework such as gradle, maven, etc, generally you can navigate to

`File > New > Project From Existing Sources...`

And then navigate to the gradle.build, pom.xml, or other framework specific build. When this project is created, all of the necessary source files should be properly identified.

Alternatively, you can also manually set the source directories by selecting the directory in the Project window, right clicking and selecting `Mark Directory As > Sources Root`.

See also:

- [Importing Project from Maven Model](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-maven-model.html)
- [Importing Project from Gradle Model](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-gradle-model.html)
- [Configuring Content Roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html)

Comment: `File > New > Module From Existing Sources...` might be a better choice in this case (since these actually seem to be different modules of the same root project): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-module-by-importing-existing-sources.html

Answer (score 84):

If you get the directory from some version system and it has a maven `pom.xml` configuration file, here's a solution:

- Find the `pom.xml` in the directory.
- Right click the `pom.xml`.
- Then you can see the popup windows. Select the last item `"add as maven project file"`.
- Then, the maven build tool can automatically discern the directory as an module and import the specified jar dependencies.

Comment: @VikrantGoel looks like this should be separate answer, not the comment

Comment: it's `Add as Maven Project` now (IntelliJ 2019.2)

Answer (score 2):

You should mark this folder as `source` directory in project settings or with right-click on folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced similar problem. I had no recognition of modules in Intellij Idea after I pushed new modules to github repository, and then tried to pull changes on another computer (where old version of project already exists, but without modules). And nothing helped (manual marking of source roots and manual import of modules) except competely removing the old version and cloning it again from repository.
After fresh cloning, all the modules are recognized correctly.
May be solution with maven's pom.xml also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In case of project Jigsaw Java modules (I copied and pasted the other module), removing `.idea` directory and opening the project again did the trick.